# Linq Code with Distinct or GroupBy not working

Tags: c#, list, linq, drop-down-menu, unique

I am trying to populate a list so I can put it in a ViewBag and into a DropDownList. I want it so that the dropdown list will only show the unique values. 
I tried two methods. One being the Distinct which didnt work. That showed all the results and repeated them. Below I will insert the code.

```
List<Strategy> list = new List<Strategy>();

List<SelectListItem> groupListItems = list
    .Where(w => w.Group != null)
    .Select(group => new SelectListItem { Value = group.Group, Text = group.Group })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
ViewBag.Groupddl = new SelectList(groupListItems, "Value", "Text")
    .Distinct();
```

And then I was reading some posts and people suggest the GroupBy method which I tried. This resulted in only one item(the first one) populating the dropdownlist even though there are more unique values that should be there.

```
List<Strategy> list = new List<Strategy>();

List<SelectListItem> groupListItems = list
    .GroupBy(w => w.Group != null)
    .Select(group => new SelectListItem {
        Value = group.First().Group,
        Text = group.First().Group })
   .ToList();
ViewBag.Groupddl = new SelectList(groupListItems, "Value", "Text")
    .Distinct();
```

How do I get it so that the dropdown list only populates all the unique values with no repetition?

Comment: Distinct will use the class Equals method to check if two items are equals. The default is check if the reference are the same, which will not be for your case. You could override the Equals and GetHash methods of your SelectListItem class to check if Value and Text are equal.

Comment: What is "Strategy".  I assume that is a class in your project?  Did you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class?

Comment: The `IComparable` of `SelectListItem` is not working as intended because it relies on the default implementation (and you want to compare only two properties). You shoud change your code slightly, not doing `.Select(group => new SelectListItem)` but using other type and doing `.Select(group => group.First().Group).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: In plain words. You should `list --> data --> distinct --> List<SelectListItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `SelectListItem` uses reference equality. Therefore `Distinct` does not work on it. Apply `Distinct` to the group value itself

```
List<SelectListItem> groupListItems = list
    .Select(w => w.Group)
    .Where(g => g != null)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(g => new SelectListItem { Value = g, Text = g })
    .ToList();
```

Another possibility to fix it, is to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `SelectListItem`.

In your second code snippet you don't group by the group, but by the Boolean resulting from the comparison `w.Group != null`.

```
.GroupBy(w => w.Group != null)
```

So, if all of them are not null, you get only one group with the Key = `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works just the way it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirstOrDefault() to get only the first element

```
ViewBag.Groupddl = new SelectList(groupListItems, "Value", "Text").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How does this answers OP question? He want distinct values, not the first one